# Replace date with current date

Tags: text-processing, date

I have a file `abc.fil` whose content is in the format `yyyymmdd.xyz.doc`. I want to `cat` that file `abc.fil` such that I get the output as `20150127.xyz.doc`. Can any one please help me to resolve this problem.

Sample file:

```
$ cat abc.fil
o/p: yyyymmdd.xyz.doc
yyyymmdd.mno.dat
abc.txt
```

Output expected: Instead of `yyyymmdd` I want the current date to be displayed in the same order.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with cat. Actually, nothing at all. You just want to replace a pattern with a current date.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed "s/yyyymmdd/$(date '+%Y%m%d')/g" abc.fil
```

That replaces the string `yyyymmdd` with the current date formatted as desired.

**Edit:**

If `yyyymmdd` is just the format of the date you want to replace, then use that command (assumes GNU `sed`):

```
sed -r "s/[12][0-9]{3}[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]/$(date '+%Y%m%d')/g" abc.fil
```

The long regular expression pattern means the following: The first digit can be 1 or 2 (`[12]`), the next three can be everything from 0 to 9 (`[0-9]`), that's the year. Now the month: the first digit can be 0 or 1 and the second can be everything from 0 to 9 (`[01][0-9]`). And at last the same with the day.

Comment: Why do you have so many `{1}`s? They do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Doorknob I see, they are not necessary, I updated my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
> today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
> sed "s/yyyymmdd/${today}/g" abc.fil
o/p: 20150127.xyz.doc
20150127.mno.dat
abc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
cat abc.fil | sed s/yyyymmdd/`date +%Y%m%d`/
```

Comment: Why the downvote? That command will work in csh/tcsh and in Bourne-like shells provided `$IFS` doesn't contain digits (`cat` is redundant though).

Comment: Not from me :-)

Comment: It's better to use `$(...)` instead of backticks. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: Why is it better (appart from the need to escape the quotes for this forum)?

Comment: I'll answer my question myself. It isn't better, it only makes a difference which is that the quotes retain the meaning of the backslash while $() does not treat it specially. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html